# Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)

Tags: python, json, file

I have simple Python code to read a JSON file, but I keep getting the error `Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)` when I use `json.load()` function.

```
import json


f = open(json_path)
for line in f:
    print(line)
    print(json.loads(line))
```

Many have encountered the same error, but it seems primarily for formatting. I don't see any issues with the formatting here. My double quotations are fine too.

This is my JSON file example :

```
{
  "ABCD": {
    "IMAGE.jpg":{
      "LOSS":"CAR",
      "UNIT_ID":"14_1",
      "DESCRIPTION":"Marginal",
      "IMAGE_NAME":"car.jpg",
      "CODE":"SURFACE",
      "DEPTH":1.5
    }
  },
  "DEFG": {},
  "HIJK": {},
  "LMNO": {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to load the JSON file line by line. Instead, you need to load the whole thing at once. Unlike in CSV files, JSON is **not** line based. Individually, each line means nothing; it only has a meaning when it's all together.

Also, because you're trying to load a file, it's better to use `json.load()` instead of `json.loads()`. `json.loads()` expects a string, while one can just pass a file handler directly `json.load()` without needing to read first:

```
import json

with open('test.json') as f:
    print(json.load(f))
```